# How can I manually change the language using i18next and be detected in a utility file?

Tags: reactjs, i18next

I am using i18next in my React app and have a dropdown so that the user can change the language via `i18next.changeLanguage()`.
Rendered components register the change, however I have a utility (.ts) file that is using translations with `import { t } from 'i18next'` and looks like this -

```
export const steps = [
  {
    label: t('common:steps.applicant_information'),
    value: 1,
    relatedTasks: [tasks.confirmPersonalDetails],
    component: ApplicantInfo
  },
  {
    label: t('common:steps.contacts'),
    value: 2,
    component: Contacts,
    relatedTasks: [tasks.confirmResponsibleParties]
  }
]
```

and the language change doesn't register, presumably because it doesn't get re-rendered. How can I solve this?

Comment: I'd probably look at turning `steps` into a simple getter function that returns the data (with the current translation applied) rather than a static array.

Answer (score 0):

how about trying `useTranslation` hook from `react-i18next` instead of directly importing `t` from `i18next` in your utility(.ts) file?

```
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

const { t } = useTranslation();
```

if it doesn't work, additionally try to change `steps` array to function that return the array like below.

```
// steps file
export const getSteps = () => [ ... ];
```

and then in your React component that uses the `steps` array, call the `getSteps` function.

```
import { getSteps } from './stepfile';

// inside your component
const steps = getSteps();
```

I think this `getSteps` function returns translations dynamically whenever the language changes in your app.

hopefully it works :)